# Python plot y axis average label won't show and the Dates ar all crowdet

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I want to have a Label for the red y axis avreage line but it wont show up as a label. Also all the Dates from the dataset are all crowdet

This is my Code:

```py
def plot_data(measurement):


    df = pd.read_csv("out.csv")
    date = df["date"]
    value = df[measurement]

    plt.plot(date, value, label=host[0:7] + ", " + measurement + ", " + date_til[0:10] + " " +  date_from[11:19] + "-" + date_til[11:19])
    plt.title(measurement)
    plt.xlabel("date")
    plt.ylabel(measurement)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    average = df[measurement].mean()

    plt.axhline(y=average, color='r', linestyle='-', label="average Ø ≈ " + str(average))

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5, forward=True)

    #today = date.today()
    #print(today)
    filename = "plots/plot_" + date_from[0:10] + ".png"

    fig.savefig(filename, dpi=100)

    print("\rPlot: Done ✔️")
```

This is the resullt of the plot:
[image: broken_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show `average Ø ≈ ...` label in legend you need to call `plt.legend` after `ax.axhline`:

```
...

average = df[measurement].mean()

plt.axhline(y=average, color='r', linestyle='-', label="average Ø ≈ " + str(average))

plt.legend()

...
```

---

x axis label crowding happens when you are plotting x axis as `str` in place of `datetime`, so you need to do this conversion with [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) firstly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['date'], df['value'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['date'], df['value'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

You can further customize x axis ticks with:

```
import matplotlib.dates as md

# set spacing between ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval = 3))

# set tick label format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

# set tick label rotation to 45°
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 45)
```

[image]

Comment: what is `color='r'` for and can i put HEX inside.

Comment: `'r'` means `'red'` color. You can pass a HEX code as `color = '#00AA00'`

Comment: but why is the graph blue

Comment: Because that `color` is the parameter of the `axhline` not the line's one, so the line has its default blue color and the horizontal line is red (or the color you want to use)